# Bind in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, bind, undefined

I have a problem with jQuery code that works fine in Firefox but not in IE9. In the console I get the following error:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get the value of the property "bind" object null
>   or undefined

That sends me to this part of my script:

```
        //upload files
    this.uploadFiles.bind('click', this, function(e){
        if(e.data.settings.enable) e.data.uploadAll();
        return false;
    });

    //remove all files from list
    this.removeFiles.bind('click', this, function(e){
        if(e.data.settings.enable) e.data.clearQueue();
        return false;
    });
```

Entire js is downloadable here
http://tinyurl.com/c9jl2x8 (ajaxupload.js)

The script was downloaded from 
http://codecanyon.net/item/real-ajax-multi-uploader/805976

The author claims it should work in all navigators ... but hell it's not lol Did i do something wrong or what?

I am using the jQuery file that came with the script (jQuery v1.7.2) i tryed using the 1.9, same result. Seems to me that the syntaxe of the code will need to change in order for the script to work properly but i don't have enought jQuery knowledge to get it working

Comment: try using `on` method. http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: Nope this is what i get
Unable to get value of the property "on": null object or undefined

Comment: `on()` takes different parameters than `bind()`.

Comment: This is what i did to get the above error:

this.uploadFiles.on('click', function(e){
if(this.e.data.settings.enable) this.e.data.uploadAll();
});

Comment: generally I would first look for the error in my own code before blaming others. Can you post your code where you call the external script (with some context).

Comment: This is a temperary script to try the uploader
http://tinyurl.com/c4wvlx3
It works in forefox but not in explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was commented in the library where it defines uploadFiles/removeFiles

```
//Upload all button
this.uploadFiles = $('<a class="'+bs_upload+'" title="' + _('Upload all files') + '" />').append('<span class="'+bs_u_icon+'"></span> <span>' + _('Start upload') + '</span>').appendTo(this.fieldSet);

//remove files button
this.removeFiles = $('<a class="'+bs_remove+'" title="' + _('Remove all') + '" />').append('<span class="'+bs_r_icon+'"></span> <span>' + _('Remove all') + '</span>').appendTo(this.fieldSet);
```

You need to uncomment it so it will stop throwing that error

[image]

Comment: Thx for joining in wirey. Unfortunatly, that did not solve the problem http://tinyurl.com/c4wvlx3

Comment: @PatrickSimard I don't see that code inside a document.ready function in the url you provided

Comment: Yeah i just took it out. When i wrap it up in $(function(){}); the ajaxupload function is not reconised

Comment: @PatrickSimard huh? can you add it back in so I can see what's going on?

Comment: Ok it's back like you asked it.

Comment: @PatrickSimard ah ok.. the document.ready function isn't need since you have the script after the element...  Hmm..  another thing you can try commenting out all the extra options and just have the url - I'm still looking at the documentation to see if anything is missing